# Local conservation of charge does not imply global conservation of charge?

Tags: charge, conservation-laws

In order for a set of $\rho, \vec{J}$ functions to conserve charge locally.

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = - \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

Consider

$$\vec{J} = x \hat i$$

Does this have a valid counterpart for $\rho$?

$\nabla \cdot [x \hat i] = -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$

$1 = -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$

$\rho = - t + k$

Thus $$\iiint \rho dv ≠ c$$

The total charge in the universe is constantly decreasing.

Why so? What is it about this infinite distribution of charge that causes local conservation of charge to not actually conserve charge globally.

Comment: "Why so?" Because you explicitly designed it so.

Answer (score 0):

> Why so?

Because you explicitly picked an example that does so:
$$
Q(t) = -Vt\;,
$$
where I set your $k=0$, and where $V$ is the volume (any volume).

You explicitly picked a current density that is in the negative direction for negative x and in the positive direction for positive x. Consider a pillbox volume along the x-axis with its center at zero. Clearly charge is only flowing *out* of the box... So the charge inside is always decreasing with time. This is how *you* explicitly designed the charge and current densities.

> The total charge in the universe is constantly decreasing...

> What is it about this infinite distribution of charge that causes local conservation of charge to not actually conserve charge globally.

Because charge is flowing out of your "universe" at the $x = +\infty$ *and* $x=-\infty$ edges (and not flowing *in* from anywhere). So the total charge has to decrease. This is true not only for your "universe" as a whole, but also for any volume.

Comment: I completely understand it for a finite volume, however I was under the impression that $\iiint_{AllSpace}$ would constant using local conservation of charge. However I now realise this is only then case given $\vec{J}$ is finite and does not extend to infinity. I will leave this post unanswered as of yet, as I would like someone to explain if net charge = constant,  Is  another condition on charge  as the local conservation and this condition only agree at all times if J is non infinite , which we have no reason to assume it is

Comment: Why should the integral over "all space" be constant? Clearly it is decreasing like $-Vt$ for any finite approximation to "all space." I have already explain that your "net charge" is not constant. It is clearly not constant. What else could you need explained?

Comment: I am now not arguing that for this specific current density the integral of all of space is constant. Clearly the math showing it is not, and is decreasing in time. However, intuitively, "charge conservation" would seem to mean that the total charge in the universe is unchanging with time. I am now stating that local charge conservation is not enough of a mathematical condition to impose this fact. We must also have J vanishes at infinity. I am aware now that local charge conservation doesnt mean the total charge in the universe is constant

Comment: "I am now..." What do you mean? You asked a question and you got an answer. If you now have a different question, then pose it in a different post. It is not fair to answerers for you to create a moving target. This is a question and answer site that is supposed to be helpful to everyone, not just you.

Comment: My last statement in the original question is about global conservation of charge, ie the total charge in the universe is constant.I think my comments are perfectly inline with my original question

Comment: My original  question is about the local charge conservations ability to have global charge conservation. And asking conditions for them to be equal[or not equal]

Answer (score -1):

**Heres an explanation I am somewhat satisfied with:**

$$\iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da} =- \iiint \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV$$

The rate at which charge flows through a surface, is the rate at which charge decreases in the volume enclosed by that surface.

I think one natural interpretation of this is that charge is a conserved quantity. It is also intuitive that if charge leaves one volume, it appears in another volume [provided the boundaries of the surfaces are connected]

**Proving this mathematically:**

Consider a surface $A_{1}$  and a composite surface $A_{2}, A_{2'}$, such that the volume enclosed by these surfaces, $V_{1}, V_{2}$ share a boundary [at $A_{1}$]

[image]

For surface 2, applying the continuity equation:

$$\iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da} =- \iiint \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV$$

$$\iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da}_{2} + \iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da}_{2'}  =- \iiint \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV_{2}$$

Because the 2 surfaces share a boundary, but with opposite surface orientations,

$$-\vec{da}_{1} =  \vec{da}_{2}$$

Substituting we are left with

$$-\iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da}_{1} + \iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da}_{2'}  =- \iiint \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV_{2}$$

Let's assume that charge does not leave volume 2 by the surface $A_{2'}$, as such its surface integral is zero

$$\iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da}_{1}  = \iiint \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV_{2}$$

Meaning that the rate at which charge leaves volume 1 through the boundary of  the surface enclosing it, is equal to rate at which charge enters volume 2.

**Global conservation of charge:**

If the total amount of charge in the universe is constant

$$\iiint_{\infty} \rho dV = C$$
$$\iiint_{\infty} \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} dV = 0$$

Applying the continuity equation:

$$\iint_{\infty} \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da} = 0$$

This is the condition on which charge in the universe is globally conserved. **Local conservation of charge is not enough of a restriction on $\rho,\vec{J}$ for the amount of charge to be constant in the universe, as alot of people would naturally think.**

**Charge leaving the universe:**

If the above condition is not met, the total charge in the universe is not constant.

From our original proof, if charge leaves the through the surface of some volume, it can be thought of as "going" to the volume connected to it.

Applying the same formula to a chosen volume of infinity

$$\iint_{\infty} \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da}_{\infty}  = \iiint_{?} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV_{?}$$

If the surface is chosen to be infinity,  What volume can the charge leaving through the boundary enter? Infinity is infinite, defining a surface above infinity is not possible. Local conservation of charge runs into a big error when the surface is infinity. Charge cannot "go" anywhere, as the volume enclosed by the boundary of infinity, to another surface greater than infinity, does not exist.

Charge simply dissappears if the surface integral is not zero at infinity.

**Solutions:**

I think the most satisfying fix is saying that charge IS globally conserved. As such the surface integral at infinity is always zero, no charge dissappears.

Although a greater condition is that $\vec{J}$ vanishes at infinity, this would prevent charge disappearing from the universe  and would also fix the "charge moving into a volume which does not exist"  as the former condition would still allow for charge to enter a volume which does not exist, if the sum of charge entering and leaving this imaginary volume cancels out.

Or perhaps defining a infinite surface is not sensible.

Comment: Any down vote  comments? I believe i accurately and more effectively answered my original question **"Why so? What is it about this infinite distribution of charge that causes local conservation of charge to not actually conserve charge globally."**

Comment: Any reason for the down vote,I think my question is perfectly valid.